# Spring Data MongoDB Mapping Exception

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a strange problem with Spring Data Mongo 1.2.3.RELEASE when persisting my object. There is a part from the trace :

```
2015-05-11 11:43:08.431 ERROR 2552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].
[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] 
in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested 
exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: 
Ambiguous field mapping detected! Both private int 
java.text.NumberFormat.maximumIntegerDigits and private int 
java.text.DecimalFormat.maximumIntegerDigits map to the same field name 
maximumIntegerDigits! Disambiguate using @Field annotation!] with root cause

org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: 
Ambiguous field mapping detected! Both private int 
java.text.NumberFormat.maximumIntegerDigits and private int 
java.text.DecimalFormat.maximumIntegerDigits map to the same field name 
maximumIntegerDigits! Disambiguate using @Field annotation!
```

My entity class is :

```
@Document(collection = "gab")
public class Gab implements Serializable{
@Id
private String numero;
private String nom;
private String ip;
private CustomDate gabLastConnected;
// Getters and setters ....
```

The embedded document is :

```
public class CustomDate {
private DateFormat format;

private Date date;

private Long annee;
private Long mois;
private Long jour;
private Long heure;
private Long minute;
private Long seconde;
// Getters ans setters
```

The rest method that calls Mongo Repository for persistance :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;
@Autowired
private GabRepository gabRepository;
@RequestMapping(value = "/gab/ping", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void ping_gab(Authentication authentication,HttpServletRequest request){
    System.err.println("num GAB " + authentication.getName());
    Gab g = gabRepository.findOne(authentication.getName());
    Gab s = new Gab(g.getNumero());
    s.setGabLastConnected(new CustomDate(new Date()));
    System.err.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
    s.setIp(request.getRemoteAddr());
    System.err.println(s);
    gabRepository.save(s);
}
}
```

Comment: That `maximumIntegerDigits` field must come from somewhere. Is that the only `Document` in your application? Can you check where that field could be defined?

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane Nicoll, the problem was caused by the DateFormat field. I forgot to mark it as `@Transient` that caused the MappingException. Adding this annotation to the field solved the problem.